# <suffix> invalid DN 21 (Invalid syntax) openldap

Tags: openldap

Actually based on http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html said that i can converting slapd.conf to cn=config format.

So for this purpose i try to make slapd.conf file on server which have role provider like bellow:

```
database bdb
suffix dc=mydomain,dc=org
rootdn cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=org
directory /var/lib/ldap/db
index objectclass,entryCSN,entryUUID eq

overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100

database config
rootpw mypassword
```

Then i try to convert that file using slaptest command, but i got error message like bellow :

```
$ slaptest -f slapd.conf -v
slapd.conf: line 2: <suffix> invalid DN 21 (Invalid syntax)
slaptest: bad configuration file
```

Actually my suffix is absolutely right, but why always "invalid DN"

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 12):

You probably have solved it by now, but for the benefit of the googles out there...

Your suffix is *not* absolutely right because it uses the domainComponent attribute  "dc=" but you haven't added the schema that defines it. So until that is done the distinguished name is an unknown and "invalid DN".

Explanation: In the core.schema file (typically in /etc/openldap/schemas/, at least for RedHat/CentOS RPMs) you can find this (and much more that is needed):

```
# RFC 1274 + RFC 2247
attributetype ( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25
        NAME ( 'dc' 'domainComponent' )
        DESC 'RFC1274/2247: domain component'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

What you have to do it to include this schema file to your configuration by adding *this* to the beginning (assuming the file is at this path, adjust as needed):

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
```

You probably also need other schema files, but this will solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with too minimal of a file, I added a few extra details and it works

```bash
#slapd.conf

#schemas to use
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

#log
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

########################################
#####   dbm database definitions    ####
########################################

database bdb
suffix dc=server,dc=com
rootdn cn=Manager,dc=server,dc=com
rootpw secret

#database directory
directory       /var/lib/ldap

#end
```

According to [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01978918) you might only be missing the pidfile location as it changed between versions but you will eventually add the rest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

well you should delete defaults files before run your test:

example on CentOS:

```
rm -rf /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*
```

and in database directory, should have a DB_CONFIG file

all archives with ldap-user-granted (chown ldap:ldap)

include this files in #schemas to use

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
```